# Cassandra ring configuration

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to connect Apache Cassandra nodes into a ring. They are not Datastax versions, but Cassandra 1.2.8 from the Apache website. When trying to add one as the seed of the other I get following exception:

```
Unable to find compaction strategy class 'com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.compaction.CFSCompactionStrategy'
```

Before that I change the "listen_address" and "rpc_address" to local IP address of each node. Next step I add one IP as a seed to another node. The nodes start up, an exception is printed but both nodes run fine until restart. After restarting either node the exception is printed and nodes do not run.

This is very strange - I do not have any DSE components.

Answer (score 1):

Did you previously use any DSE components?  If you did and are using the same data directory on any of your nodes, it may find old column families that were created with this compaction strategy.  If you have no data you want in the data directories on all your nodes, you should clear them by stopping all nodes, deleting the directories, then starting the nodes.

Or if you have any DSE nodes still up, they may be joining the new cluster and propagating their schema, so creating column families with this compaction strategy.  You can find out by looking in the logs and seeing which nodes try to connect.  If any aren't from your 1.2.8 ring then this is probably the cause.

Comment: I don't think so - one machine is clean VM and another one does not seem to have any traces of DSE.
I also deleted "/data" and "/log" folders each time I would try to set up the ring.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you either had a DSE Analytics node in your ring at some point, or you restored your schema from someplace that had an Analytics node.

I would check if you have the folder /etc/dse/ on your VM, that would mean DSE was installed there.

To just wipe the node and start from scratch schema wise, you can stop the node, remove the /system/schema_* folders, then start the node.  When it starts it will have no schema.  Re-create any keyspaces/column families you had before, and they will get read from disk.